# How do I paint a ceiling properly?

Tags: basement, ceiling, paint

I can’t seem to get this right for the life of me. I’ve applied primer, 2 coats of paint and it looks terrible! Look at the roller lines, the texture etc

I’ve used a good quality ceiling paint, 10mm rollers , I don’t apply too much pressure etc

I used a flat paint. I paint in straight lines following the longest wall for the first coat and then paint across for the second coat.

Can this be fixed ?

[image]

Comment: Describe what it is you don't like or would like to fix. Describe your technique, how do you paint, where do you start, do you roll randomly or in straight lines across always working off a wet edge form one end to the other?

Comment: I can see joint lines It is hard to tell from the photo but did you use a gloss or semi gloss paint? Any finish imperfections in the ceiling will be less evident  with a flat paint.

Comment: Believe it or not it’s supposed to be a flat ceiling paint.

Comment: It looks like you're not putting enough paint on - the roller needs to be thoroughly and evenly covered with paint and don't roll it out too far. You obviously don't want the roller dripping but it should be be well loaded with paint. Further coats will cover it OK.

Comment: Describe what it is you don't like or would like to fix. Describe your technique, how do you paint, where do you start, do you roll randomly or in straight lines across always working off a wet edge form one end to the other?

Comment: @AlaskaMan sorry about that, I updated my post about an hour ago. I should of clarified that in the comment section. I work along the long side of the room for the first coat and the other side for the second coat. This is also new drywall that was primed before hand.